# Martian Abiogenesis?

Tags: abiogenesis, astrobiology

In the [Miller-Urey experiment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Urey_experiment) the probability of the chemical origin of life under (hypothetical) early Earth atmospheric conditions were assessed. For that water, methane, ammonia, and hydrogen were sealed in a bowl, heated and struck by artificial lightning (see [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Urey_experiment) for the experimental setup). After cooling the mixture down several complex organic molecules (e.g. amino acids) were found by paper chromatography.

So my question is what would happen if instead of using early Earth gases, one puts a concoction similar to current or early atmospheric gases found on/expected to once be found on Mars.

Is it possible to foresee how well that experiment might do and what results it could bring?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I think your question is valid but please do not use references as parts of your questions. Rather (briefly) describe the experiment (the Miller-Urey experiment will probably known by almost everyone around here) and provide a reference for deeper reeding. I edited your question accordingly. Feel free to add anything to or change my edits.